# Installing a product as a feature through emdebbed msi

Tags: windows-installer

### The Problem

Currently I have a legacy product that installs a service as a feature using a Merge Module (.msm). However the same service may be installed as a standalone Product via an MSI package (.msi) that basically embeds the Merge Module (.msm).

This leads to a necessity of complex workarounds on updates, since the Service can be installed on the same machine either as a standalone Product (that has its own Product Code GUID) or as a feature (which doesn't have its own Product Code GUID).

More over, the Service's msi and msm are configured via Wix, but the main product's installer is created via InstallShield 2010.
Also the Custom Action tables are merged upon the Main product installer's generation. And there are some custom actions within the Service's installation that require a particular order.

### Possible solution

I know that I can basically run the Service's .msi installer as a Main product's Custom Action.
But there are several concerns:

1. Is it possible to show space requirements for a feature that installs the Service? As a subprocess it would not take part in the main installer sequence...
2. Is it possible to show progress information in the main installation process?
3. What is a safe way to migrate msm to msi during an Upgrade, if a new Service as a Product must be installed in the same subfolder by default?

Comment: Your first sentence confuses me. You can't install Merge Modules per se, they must be merged into an MSI to be used. Most of your concerns shouldn't be issues if you're installing the service using the Windows Installer. Custom actions, of course, mean all bets are off... need more details to really understand.

Comment: @RobMensching that is what i meant: it is installed with main product's setup.exe where it is merged by Installshield. Or it can be installed as a standalone product via msi (where it is merged into by wix).

Comment: Unless you've introduced complexity with custom actions, reference counting by the Windows Installer should just work in this case then. Two MSIs can install a shared resource (merged in from the same Merge Module) and it will only uninstall when both MSIs are removed. This is actually one of the design goals of Merge Modules. Well-written custom actions can (and should) operate the same by being Component-based. There aren't enough details to understand why you are face problems.

Comment: @RobMensching I don't want to metnion all the hacks there are in that legacy project. But one of them is referencing the folder where the service-product has been installed. In case it is installed as a standalone Product, there's a Product Code GUID which can be acquired via an Upgrade Table. But when the service-product is installed via merging a module, it does not have its own Product Code. By many traits the Service-Product (it installs a service, but not limited to a service) is a standalone-product.

Comment: @RobMensching so I know that I can launch a silent msi install as a custom action. But there are some questions I have mentioned that I want answers to ("Possible Solution" section).